# How to chain and combine RACSignals correct in case of auth?

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactive-cocoa

I fighting with it few days, and still no success, please help somebody. I hope this question pretty stupid) 
So, I have Class for connecting social network. At first I need to check - is my session valid I do this like :

```
self.isSessionValid = [RACSignal combineLatest:
@[RACObserve([FMSettingsManager shared], vkToken),
  RACObserve([FMSettingsManager shared], vkUserID),
  RACObserve([FMSettingsManager shared], vkExperationDate)]
reduce:^id(NSString* token,NSString* userID, NSDate* experationDate){
       return @(token.length > 0 &&
                userID.length > 0 &&
                experationDate &&
                NSOrderedDescending == [experationDate compare:[NSDate date]]);
}];
```

After that I need to call auth if my session is invalid, so I created method. Class FMVKAuthorizationVC has a public property, which indicates current state for login process.

```
 - (RACSignal*)authorization
      {
          RACSignal* shouldStartAuth = [self.isSessionValid not];
         [shouldStartAuth map:^id(NSNumber* value)
         {
            if (value.boolValue)
            {
                FMVKAuthorizationVC* vc = [FMVKAuthorizationVC new];
                FMNavigationController* nc = [[FMNavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];
                [[[FMScreenManager shared].currentRootController.viewControllers lastObject] presentViewController:nc
                                                                                                          animated:YES completion:nil];
                return [[RACObserve(vc, state) distinctUntilChanged] map:^id(NSNumber* value)
                 {
                     if (value.integerValue == VKAuthStateError)
                     {
                         [FMErrorManager showErrorForKey:@"APP_ERROR_VK_AUTH"];
                         return @(NO);
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         return @(YES);
                     }
                 }];
            }
             else
             {
                 return @(YES);
             }
        }];
    return shouldStartAuth;
}
```

After that I need to log in user, in 2 cases : if I already authorised and my session valid, OR authoziation is finished and my session comes to valid state.

This authorisation I need to call several times before request start, I can't use solution with defer: because in case of error in request, I need recreate it and send again on another call.

```
- (RACSignal*)loginUser
{
    return [[[self authorization] flattenMap:^RACStream *(id value) {
        return [self loadUserProfile];
    }] flattenMap:^RACStream *(id value) {
        return [self loadUserProfilePhoto];
    }];
}
```

Comment: Did my answer make sense? Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `-retry` or `-retry:` to retry infinitely or a finite number of times after an error.

You might also want to return the mapping that you added to `shouldStartAuth`, instead of returning `shouldStartAuth`. Currently the mapping you have there is dead code.

If you have access to the source for `FMVKAuthorizationVC`, you could have a static method that handles most of the guts of your mapping and returns a signal. Maybe something like this:

```
- (RACSignal*)authorization
{
    RACSignal* shouldStartAuth = [self.isSessionValid not];
    return [shouldStartAuth
           flattenMap:^ RACSignal * (id value)
           {
               if (value.boolValue)
                   return [FMVKAuthorizationVC authorizationSignal];
               else
                   return [RACSignal return:@1];
           }
    }];

}
```

`-[FMVKAuthorizationVC authorizationSignal]` could potentially be responsible for constructing the view controller and passing along a signal, assuming you can modify that code.

Comment: Sorry for a very BIG delay, yes, that helps, thank you!